# How to get ng-model value of Radio button using Jasmine and Karma in AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to Jasmine and Karma

I am testing an AngularJS application using Jasmine+Karma

My Html looks like this:

```html
<div id="form">
  <div id="car-type">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="$ctrl.carType" ng-change="$ctrl.onTypeChange()" name="carType"
                        ng-value="true"/>
                <span class="label">Honda</span>
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$ctrl.carType" ng-change="$ctrl.onTypeChange()" name="carType"
                        ng-value="false"/>
                <span class="label">Mazda</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I try getting the value of the model bound to the input radio button, true is returned (because of ng-value I believe):

```js
var wrapperForm = element[0].querySelector('#form');

// Returns true
console.log(wrapperForm.querySelector('#car-type input').value);
```

But, I want the model value bound to the radio button.

I don't know how to retrieve the model value bound to the radio button ($ctrl.carType).

Is there a way to retrieve it using the querySelector?

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
document.querySelector("#car-type [type=radio]").getAttribute("ng-model")
```

However, you have two instances, you might want querySelectorAll instead.

Comment: Tried doing this. I get this error:
TypeError: NamedNodeMap is not a constructor

Comment: @CoderPJ you are right. Please excuse me for the typo. Edited my answer.